# RStudio on Ubuntu (GNOME): settings reset on launch

Tags: r

I have a HiDpi screen, and require the zoom setting to be at 200% within RStudio for it to be usable. Each time I launch the application from the launcher, however, the zoom setting is reset back to the default.

Starting RStudio from the terminal with sudo privileges launches it with the desired zoom level.

```
sudo rstudio
```

Why does it work with elevated privileges? I don't feel comfortable launching R with elevated privileges every time.

Comment: `sudo` - the solution to - and cause of - all life's problems. Probably the *first* time you ran it with `sudo`, part (or all) of your `~/.rstudio-desktop` became owned by `root` and is now no longer writeable when you want to make changes as user?

Comment: You're right, there were folders in `~/.rstudio-desktop` owned by sudo rather than my user. Updated the privileges though and it's still launching at 100% zoom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the user has write and read permissions to file `.config/Rstudio/desktop.ini`. This allows RStudio to save the zoom level.

Comment: Works! Root user only had read and execute permissions